# Handle exceptions in constructor's body

Tags: c++, exception, network-programming

I am currently trying to implement a class of a TCP server in C++ that uses C functions to acquire some of its resources and to give the class functionality in general. I am following **Beej's Guide To Network Programming** (http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/), which is recommended in multiple posts about network programming.

However, the guide is in C and I wanted to give the whole a more object-oriented design and after trying out different things, I came up with the idea of packing the basic routine of a TCP server (create `socket()`, `bind()`, `listen()`, `accept()`) into the constructor's body of my class.

In that way, when a TCP server object (with a port number passed to it) is created, it would be ready to establish a connection with a client.

Nonetheless, the functions mentioned above may not work, i.e. one has to account for exception-handling and I don't know if handling exceptions inside the constructor's body is bad practice (I am not aware of the possible consequences).

So my question is, whether it is good to handle exceptions in a constructor's body or not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can handle bad states, a constructor is as good a place as any other, in my opinion. Throwing an exception in a constructor means you cannot instantiate a non-valid object. Depending on the context of the project, throwing exceptions may be forbidden at all, but if it is not, this would be fine by me as the user is now forced to handle the bad state one way or another. So, throwing exceptions in constructors would be fine be me, but that is more of a personal opinion, than a best practice. Cannot say anything about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That clarifies a lot :)